# Saving Visio drawing after update an embedded Excel object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, visio, embedded-object

I have a problem with my VBA code.

My task is to create VBA script which will scan directory for Visio drawings, update an embedded Excel object, save it and close it.

So I developed a VBA sub:

```
Dim m_visioApp as Object
Set m_visioApp = CreateObject("visio.application")


Sub UpdateVsdFile(filename As String)

    m_visioApp.Documents.Open (filename)

    For Each pageObj In m_visioApp.ActiveDocument.Pages
        For Each oleObj In pageObj.OLEObjects
            If InStr(oleObj.progID, "Excel.Sheet") > 0 Then
                oleObj.Object.Activate
                oleObj.Object.Application.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Something"
                Call oleObj.Object.RefreshAll
            End If
        Next
    Next

    m_visioApp.ActiveWindow.DeselectAll

    m_visioApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAsEx filename, visSaveAsListInMRU

    m_visioApp.ActiveDocument.Close

End Sub
```

What is not working:
- saving Visio drawing after OLE object update
- closing Visio drawing

I'm using Visio 2016 and Excel 2016.

Can any one help to check what I'm doing wrong? Or what I'm missing here?